# I want to customize the component with styled-components, but it doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Block.jsx code...

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { WHITE } from '../../constants/color';

const Wrap = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: ${WHITE};
`;

const Block = ({ children }) => {
  return <Wrap>{children}</Wrap>;
};

export default Block;
```

This is the Footer.jsx code to customize the Block component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Block from './Block';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CustomBlock = styled(Block)`
  box-shadow: 0 -4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
`;

const Footer = () => {
  return <CustomBlock>Footer</CustomBlock>;
};

export default Footer;
```

The value of box-shadow is not applied. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you are not passing the additional props that Styled Components is sending to your `Block` component, specifically the `className` prop.  Therefore, Styled Components is not able to override any values on your `Wrap` component.

Try adjusting your `Block` component to be:

```
const Block = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return <Wrap {...props}>{children}</Wrap>;
};
```

This will allow props that Styled Comonents passes to the `Block` component to be applied to the `Wrap` component, and therefore override accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `className` prop to the `Block` component in order for `styled-components` to inject the styles. You can do that by doing the following:

```
const Block = ({ children, className }) => {
  return <Wrap className={className}>{children}</Wrap>;
};
```

See styling any components in the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)